# Switching between activities without destroying the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to android so don't know what can be the solution to this problem.

I have created an app with two activities in it named these as first and second activity.
First activity launch mode is singleTask and second activity launch mode is standard.
Now when i switch from second activity to first activity i don't want to destroy the second activity.
But in this case it is getting destroyed.
So can anyone help me in suggesting how can i achieve this scenerio of switching from second activity to first without
destroying second activity.

Comment: Have you added finish() while switching from one activity to other? If yes, then remove that line.

Comment: @SnehaSarkar : No i am not using finish() while calling.This is how i am calling.   Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, First.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Your activites are in a stack. When you launch the app, the stack contains `FirstActivity`. When `FirstActivity` launches `SecondActivity`, the instance of `SecondActivity` is added to the stack. If you now want to go from `SecondActivity` to `FirstActivity`, what should happen to `SecondActivity`? Where should it go?

Comment: How do you know that `SecondActivity` is being destroyed?

Comment: If you just want to switch back and forth between the 2 activities, add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to the `Intent` you use in `startActivity()`. And remove the special `launchMode`, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because activity one is single task activity.
[Read here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). According to this

> "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.

To avoid this scenario, change launch mode of activity one to standard.

Comment: Actually my first activity is the main activity of my app.
And if i make this activity standard then it always gets created when i switch
from second to first. But i don't want to call onCreate of first activity. Instead i want to call onNewIntent.
That's why i have created it with singleTask launchmode.

Comment: In that case when first activity is started from second activity, it will finish second activity.

Answer (score 0):

No need to destroy any activity for this, i think so. Just implement this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityOne.this,ActivityTwo.class);
startActvity(intent);
```

in your **oncreate()** method of actvity

Comment: Why would you launch another activity in `onCreate`?  Surely you mean in some listener.  At any rate, they have said they're already doing this.

Answer (score -1):

You can open new activity that you want to open, without `finish()` your current / previous activity by using `finish()`.

Once you open multiple activity without `finish()` previous ones, the OS will automatically maintain the activity stack.

Comment: They already are doing this according to [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344515/switching-between-activities-without-destroying-the-activity/41345441#comment69891250_41344515) that was posted before this answer.